# Pyomo can't find solver

Tags: python, solver, pyomo

I am new to Pyomo and I have the following optimization problem (original transport problem by Dantzig):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Transport problem in Pyomo

Created on Mon Feb 15 09:55:06 2021


"""

import pyomo.environ as pyo


#Define the model

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()


#Define the sets
model.set_plants = pyo.Set(initialize=['Seattle', 'San_Diego'])
model.set_markets = pyo.Set(initialize=['New_York', 'Chicago', 'Topeka'])


# Parameters

valuesForCapacity = {'Seattle':350, 'San_Diego':600}
valuesForDemand = {'New_York': 325, 'Chicago': 300, 'Topeka': 275}

model.param_capacityOfPlants = pyo.Param(model.set_plants, initialize=valuesForCapacity)
model.param_demandAtMarkets = pyo.Param(model.set_markets, initialize=valuesForDemand)

model.param_capacityOfPlants.pprint()
model.param_demandAtMarkets.pprint()


#Parameter entry as table

valuesForDistance =  {('Seattle', 'New_York'): 2.5, ('Seattle', 'Chicago'): 1.7, ('Seattle', 'Topeka'): 1.8,
('San_Diego', 'New_York'): 2.5, ('San_Diego', 'Chicago'): 1.8, ('San_Diego', 'Topeka'): 1.4}
                      
model.param_distances = pyo.Param(model.set_plants, model.set_markets, initialize=valuesForDistance)

model.param_distances.pprint()


#Scalar
freightCostsPerUnitPerThousandMiles = 90


#Variables

model.variable_x = pyo.Var(model.set_plants,model.set_markets, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.variable_totalCosts = pyo.Var()

model.variable_x.pprint()


#Constraints

def supplyConstraintRule(model,i):
    return sum(model.variable_x[i,j] for j in model.set_markets)<=model.param_capacityOfPlants[i]


model.constraint_supply = pyo.Constraint (model.set_plants, rule=supplyConstraintRule)

def demandConstraintRule (model, j):
    return sum(model.variable_x [i,j] for i in model.set_plants)>=model.param_demandAtMarkets[j]

model.constraint_demand = pyo.Constraint (model.set_markets, rule=demandConstraintRule)
model.constraint_demand.pprint()


#Objective

def ObjectiveRule (model):
    return sum( sum(model.variable_x[i,j]* model.param_distances[i,j]*freightCostsPerUnitPerThousandMiles  for i in model.set_plants) for j in model.set_markets)


model.objective = pyo.Objective(rule=ObjectiveRule, sense =pyo.minimize)

model.objective.pprint()

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
#opt = SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="python")
opt.solve(model)
```

I tried to solve it with the statement `opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')` as recommended here https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/solving_pyomo_models.html but I get the error message "ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'glpk'". I also tried to use the statement `opt = SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="python")`but here I get the error "NameError: name 'SolverFactory' is not defined"

Do you know what I have to do in order to solve the model? I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `pyo.` to the beginning of your solver definition line, it works and gives the solution as follow:

```
param_capacityOfPlants : Size=2, Index=set_plants, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
    Key       : Value
    San_Diego :   600
      Seattle :   350
param_demandAtMarkets : Size=3, Index=set_markets, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
    Key      : Value
     Chicago :   300
    New_York :   325
      Topeka :   275
param_distances : Size=6, Index=param_distances_index, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
    Key                       : Value
     ('San_Diego', 'Chicago') :   1.8
    ('San_Diego', 'New_York') :   2.5
      ('San_Diego', 'Topeka') :   1.4
       ('Seattle', 'Chicago') :   1.7
      ('Seattle', 'New_York') :   2.5
        ('Seattle', 'Topeka') :   1.8
variable_x : Size=6, Index=variable_x_index
    Key                       : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
     ('San_Diego', 'Chicago') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
    ('San_Diego', 'New_York') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
      ('San_Diego', 'Topeka') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
       ('Seattle', 'Chicago') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
      ('Seattle', 'New_York') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('Seattle', 'Topeka') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
constraint_demand : Size=3, Index=set_markets, Active=True
    Key      : Lower : Body                                                          : Upper : Active
     Chicago : 300.0 :   variable_x[Seattle,Chicago] + variable_x[San_Diego,Chicago] :  +Inf :   True
    New_York : 325.0 : variable_x[Seattle,New_York] + variable_x[San_Diego,New_York] :  +Inf :   True
      Topeka : 275.0 :     variable_x[Seattle,Topeka] + variable_x[San_Diego,Topeka] :  +Inf :   True
objective : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
    None :   True : minimize : 225.0*variable_x[Seattle,New_York] + 225.0*variable_x[San_Diego,New_York] + 153.0*variable_x[Seattle,Chicago] + 162.0*variable_x[San_Diego,Chicago] + 162.0*variable_x[Seattle,Topeka] + 125.99999999999999*variable_x[San_Diego,Topeka]
153675.0
```

for that you need to add the following lines to your code:

```
opt = pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi', solver_io="python")
results = opt.solve(model)
print(pyo.value(model.objective))
```

As you `import Pyomo.environ as pyo`, for all the defined words in pyomo you need to add `pyo.` to the beginning. For instance, to get the value of the objective function:

```
my_obj = pyo.value(model.objective)
```

To be able to use glpk you need to install it by using:

```
conda install glpk
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32316069) if you cannot find the exe path. The following lines worked for me:

```
opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
results = opt.solve(model)
print(pyo.value(model.objective))
```

And I got the same solution: `153675.0`

Edit2:
To see all the variables' value:

```
for v in model.component_objects(pyo.Var,active=True):
    for index in v:
        print(index, ': ', pyo.value(v[index]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Oguz. When I use your suggested code (copy & paste) I get the following error message: "ApplicationError: No Python bindings available for <class 'pyomo.solvers.plugins.solvers.gurobi_direct.GurobiDirect'> solver plugin"

Comment: do you have gurobi installed in your system? PC or laptop?

Comment: Thanks Ogiz for your comment. I do not have installed anything other than Pyomo. So maybe I should not use Gurobi but the other solver (glpk)

Comment: @PeterBe see the edited answer, install glpk and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oguz for your tremendous help. It works with GLPK solver (I will later try it with Gurobi). How can I print the solution with all the variables that you posted above? Currently I only get the value of the objective function.

Comment: @PeterBe see my answer here: https://or.stackexchange.com/a/2720/39 you have a variable without any initialization value called: model.variable_totalCosts , you should comment it out.

Comment: Thanks Oguz once again for your great help and your effort. I really appreciate it. I upvoted and accepted your answer.

Comment: Hi Oguz, when I use your code from the link I get the following error message: "    for v in model.component_objects(pyo.Var,active=True):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Check the indentation. Python is sensitive to that.

Comment: I checked it 10 times and could not find anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119860/discussion-between-oguz-toragay-and-peterbe).

Comment: It says unexpected indent and points at a specific position in the line of the code. But at this position there is no indent

Comment: Thanks for your comments in the chat. I still have questions (see the chat). Would you mind replying to them? I'd appreciate every further comment from you

Comment: Hi Oguz, would you mind looking into the chat and answering my follow up questions as the suggested code by you (from the link) yields an error message. I'd appreciate any further comments from you.

Comment: Thanks Oguz for your great help :-)